# Formula similar en tableau

Tags: powerbi

Buen dia.

Tengo la siguiente formula en Power BI y no se como realizar lo mismo en tableau.

```
CountFail = 
COUNTX (
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Yield[PartNumber] ), [FailQP] > 0 ),
[FailQP]
)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.